# How to version local gradle dependencies?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dependency-management, aar

My Android project contains a library that is shipped as AAR file.

There are multiple options to include local AAR files.
I can declare a file dependency:
`implementation files('libs/mylib.aar')`

Or I can put the AAR into another module and then use a project dependency:
`implementation project(':mylibmodule')`

However, I want to specify the exact version of my library:
`mylib:1.0.0`

Unfortunately, I do not know how to specify the version without using some remote repository.
Note that I do *not* want to upload the library to JitPack, MavenCentral or similar.
All I want is to specify the version of a local AAR file.

**Update**

The AAR file is a Zip-File with the following content:

```
/proguard.txt      
/R.txt             
/AndroidManifest.xml  
/public.txt        
/classes.jar       
/res/values/values.xml
```

Note that the `AndroidManifest.xml` contains the version of the library.
However, I assume that gradle always expects a pom file for the versioning information.

Comment: You can do it only with a maven repo (public or private). The aar file doesn't contain info about version and dependencies that are in the pom file.

Comment: This is not entirely true since the AAR contains the version name within an `AndroidManifest.xml`. However, I understand that gradle expects a pom file for versioning.

Comment: @Mike76 let you answer the question, my are you specifing library version in maven? Because in that package location com.anyilbray:anymodule:<version>, could be bunch of version. And by "version" we just mean exact file. Now lets check how dependencies works, you just specifying file, with name, where version includes in NAME.

Comment: Sorry I do not get this. Do you mean that the version should equal the file name?

Answer (score 0):

I realized that gradle allows to specify a local Maven repository at a specific path:

```
repositories {
   maven {
       url uri("${projectDir}/mylibdir")
   }
}
```

To use a local Maven repository, I need to build my library as a Maven artifact. To create a Maven artifact, it suffices to create a POM file in the right subfolder.
The AAR file remains unchanged since Maven does not care about the artifact format.
Creating a Maven artifact can be automated with the `maven-publish` plugin, e.g.:

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing {
    publications {
        myRelease(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'com.foo'
            artifactId 'my-artifact'
            version '1.0.0'
            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/my-artifact.aar")
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "$buildDir/repo"
        }
    }
}
```

However, since I do not really need to use Maven, the simpler choice is to add the version to the AAR file name.
I did this with the following snippet in the `build.gradle` of my library:

```
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all {
            outputFileName = "${archivesBaseName}-${variant.name}-${defaultConfig.versionName}.aar"
        }
    }
```